# Right use of eval or avoid it in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eval

In my code, I use a specific manner to define test functions: in a cell, boolean type of tests is stored ('<=', '>=','=='...). After that I want to apply the test on specific values. The reason of why I store the type of test is specific of my code and allow me to write the code without having a prior knowledge of the kind of test. Another way could be to specify test on each boolean test using for instance `switch` but the moment I want to avoid it.

**MWE**

```
a{1}=[1 2 3 4];
a{2}=[5 1 4 6];

typeTest{1}='<=';
typeTest{2}='<';

%create function
funCheck=@(x,y)eval([num2str(x),y,'0']);

%works
funCheck(1,'<')

%apply on cell (does not work due to the array in a)
cellfun(funCheck,a,typeTest)
```

With this syntax it is to not possible to use simultaneously `eval` and vector expression...

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to find an alternative that doesn't use `eval`, do you want an alternative that allows vectorized evaluation?

Comment: I know that `eval` is not recommended so a solution to avoid it is nice but an alternative which allows vectorized evaluation is also ok :-)

Comment: Why not just store them as function handles to their equivalent functions (e.g. [`le`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/le.html) and [`lt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lt.html))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding the use of `eval` is actually quite easy nowadays in MATLAB. If you define `typeTest` as a set of function handles instead of strings, you're 99% of the way there:

```
a{1}=[1 2 3 4];
a{2}=[5 1 4 6];

typeTest{1}=@le; % <=
typeTest{2}=@lt; % <

%create function
funCheck=@(x,y)y(x,0);

%works
funCheck(1,typeTest{1})

%apply on cell
cellfun(funCheck,a,typeTest,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Note that I added `'UniformOutput',false` to the arguments of `cellfun`. This creates a cell array as output, where each cell is the rest result for one of the elements in `a` and the corresponding element in `typeTest`. That is, a{1} is checked with `TypeTest{1}` and `a{2}` is checked with `TypeTest{2}`.

I would actually create an array with all the actual tests, like so:

```
checks = { @(x)x<=3 , @(x)x>4 };
```

Now you encode the operator as well as the right operand. This gives you the flexibility to create other types of check: `@(x)var(x)<1e-3`, `@(x)max(diff(x))<1`, etc.

To apply each of these checks to each of the data arrays, you'd want to use `bsxfun`. I tried the following statement, but it didn't work correctly in Octave 3.0.0 (I think this might be a bug):

```
bsxfun( @(fun,data){fun{1}(data{1})}, checks(:)', a(:) )
```

This generates a 2x2 (number of checks times number of data arrays) cell array with the results.

An ugly alternative to the above that did work is:

```
cellfun( @(fun,data)fun(data), ...
         repmat(checks(:)',numel(a),1), ...
         repmat(a(:),1,numel(checks)), ...
         'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you I just discover `eq`, `ne`, `ge`, `gt`, `le`, `ge` syntaxes